# Basic Username and password check instead of Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

We can authenticate user by:
(1). taking username and password, and checking it directly with database.
(2). Using Spring Security(will take username and password)

If my application doesn't require authorization for certain endpoints then in that case case point (1) will be usefull as it doesn't require handling of code.

Is my understanding correct? And other than an added advanatge of authorization is there any other advantage here? In the (1) point, Is it still the correct way to authenticate the User?

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason of `spring-security` module in spring framework is to have some framework dedicated on security layer so that a normal company or developer building some application don't have to always concider how they implemented security, and if there is some hole in their security layer.

In your example we could say that spring security will also have the ability to encrypt the passwords so that not the actual passwords are stored in Database. So in case someone has access to database the credentials are not automatically disclosed.

Another case is the principal object in spring security which after authentication will have hidden the password. So you can transfer this object to see information about logged user but in case some man in the middle attack which manages to interpret the state of the object the credentials are not easily disclosed.

Many more best practices are included in the `spring-security` module as to provide additional security to the application and keep out attacks.

So to conclude using `spring-security` and using your own authentication mechanism on the most fundamental concept of credentials provided in login and compared with database would be the same, but the implementation would be a lot different since the `spring-security` module offers many more things to keep atackers out than just the implementation of this concept.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are asking besides authentication and authorisation , what other security features does spring security provides ? Some features are :

1. [CSRF support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html)
2. [CORS support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title)
3. [HttpFirewall](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/firewall.html#page-title)
4. [Security HTTP Response Headers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/headers.html)
5. [Password encoder for password storage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html#authentication-password-storage)

And also even your application does not have any role based or permission authorisation requirement now , it still needs to check if a request is come from an authenticated user or not and only allow the authenticated user to access. Otherwise, there is no points to make the user to have password to authenticate if everyone is allowed to access the application at the first place. And such checking is also a kind of authorization.

So once your application needs authentication , the next natural requirement that you cannot avoid is authorization , at least to check if the user is an authenticated user or an anonymous user.